# Positioning the cursor/mouse tip using VBA

Tags: vba

I am using Visual Basic for Applications, and in my program, I am opening Inventor parts and capturing thumbnails. I get undesirable results if the mouse tip is left hovering over the parts. I would like to be able to re-position the cursor such that it is well out of the way.

Any VBA code that accomplishes this along with the required references would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [SetCursorPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) API for this, although the UX might be horrible if you don't put it back where you found it:

```
Private Declare Sub SetCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" (x As Long, y As Long)

Sub Example()
    SetCursorPos 0, 0
End Sub
```

If you *do* want to restore the original location, just grab it with [GetCursorPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648390(v=vs.85).aspx) first.